# Why is my attempt to use Django user profiles erroring out?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a user profile object; my models.py presently reads:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    scratchpad = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user = instance)

 post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User)
```

In my settings.py I have at the top:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'models.UserProfile'
```

I am getting an error screen:

```
SiteProfileNotAvailable at /
Unable to load the profile model, check AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: SiteProfileNotAvailable
Exception Value:    
Unable to load the profile model, check AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings
Exception Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py in get_profile, line 380
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/jonathan/pim',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Server time:    Tue, 14 Feb 2012 11:48:23 -0600
```

The models.py file is in /Users/jonathan/pim.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I set things so that the UserProfile in models.py registers as a user profile?

Thanks,

--EDIT--

Regarding the site and package names, I have the UserProfile defined in models.py in the root of the project, /Users/jonathan/pim. Does this need to be moved to an application within the project? At present I do not have applications sliced off.

--SECOND EDIT--

A tarball is at http://JonathansCorner.com/project/pim.tgz

Comment: It also behaves identically if I set "user = models.OneToOneField(User)".

Answer (score 2):

i think you need

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app.UserProfile'
```

(note `app.Model`, not `models.UserProfile`)

where `app` is the name of your app

Comment: I get an identical-looking error when I set it to 'pim.UserProfile'.

Comment: @JonathanHayward: What **exactly** are the package names in your site/application tree?  Please **update** the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, `pim` is missing from the INSTALLED_APPS setting